# Unable to calculate field value from conditional formula

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column

trying to find solution for calculation of rates.
The data type returned from this formula is number.

```
if ([Role]="​Senior Software Engineer", "200", if ([Role]="​Senior Technical Consultant", "400", if ([Role]="​Project Manager", "300", if ([Role]="​Security", "350", "0"))))
```

I am still getting syntax error:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. TECHNICAL
>   DETAILS Learn more about the syntax for formulas.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation
>   ID: c8e0c79e-f22d-10a7-58e0-9677f48e53ba
>
> Date and Time: 3/11/2019 9:30:14 AM

Could you please help to find the bug?

The best would be also if will exist some option to use something like CASE in Oracle ... but I have understood from another articles that only CHOOSE is similar but with limited usage.

Anyway, neither with standard IF statement I am not able to manage that.

Thanks in advance, 
Regards, Reddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, you need to remove the space between if and the condition.

Like this:

```
=IF(Role="Senior Software Engineer","200",IF(Role="Senior Technical Consultant","400",IF(Role="Project Manager","300",IF(Role="Security","350","0"))))
```

Here is my test:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**IF function**:

Returns one value if a condition you specify evaluates to TRUE and another value if it evaluates to FALSE. Use IF to conduct conditional tests on values and formulas.

> **Syntax**:
>
> IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)

Use Formula something like this:

```
=IF(Role="Senior Software Engineer","200",IF(Role="​Senior Technical Consultant","400",IF(Role="Project Manager","300",IF(Role="Security","350","0"))))
```

**Note:**

1. Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
2. Make Sure Your Role choices matches exactly as provided in Formula(Do not add any extra spaces in formula or Role choices).

**Reference**:

1. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace all the `,` with `;`